# upload multiple files on laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, file, file-upload

I have a problem for many file uploads with the request structure for the file variables in an array. the following is the code snippet. i need a solution for this, thanks

```
$cimage = count($request->variant[$loop]['img']);
for($loops1 = 0; $loops1 < $cimage; $loops1++) {
    $variantImage      = $request->file($request->variant[$loop]['img'][$loops1]);
    $nameVariantImage  = $variant->id . '-' . date('ymdHis') . ($loops1 + 1) . '.' . $variantImage->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $uploadVariant     = $imageUpload->upload($variantImage, $nameVariantImage);
    $variantimages          = New ProductImage;
    $variantimages->product_id = $product->id;
    $variantimages->product_variant_id = $variant->id;
    $variantimages->images  = $uploadVariant;
    $variantimages->save();
    }
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: my problem is i don't know how to fetch file input on file request because it is in array form in array

Comment: if you upload a lot of files like this `$request->file('img')[$loops]`.. but what I confuse is when uploading the file where the request is the img file located in an array in the array

Comment: I am still dont know what are you trying, Please share you html input too. and also what is  $loop

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FNKR_1BTtAsMAhQ-FyicU90J_e3h7Wwf/view?usp=sharing

Comment: this is the form of request that I mean

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-zG4ibmbzK4LTrZwmf0TXmTuMIolkAyG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: there is no file on that request. and I mean your HTML input and put in the question

Comment: I tried it through postman, because I made a rest api,

Answer (score 1):

It's better using `foreach` for the looping, so based your request data the code will be like:

```
foreach ($request->variant as $varian) {
    foreach ($varian['img'] as $k => $image) {
        $nameVariantImage                  = $variant->id.'-'.date('ymdHis').($k + 1).'.'
            .$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filePath                          = Storage::putFileAs(
            "products/variant",
            $image,
            $nameVariantImage
        );
        $variantimages                     = new ProductImage;
        $variantimages->product_id         = $product->id;
        $variantimages->product_variant_id = $variant->id;
        $variantimages->images             = $filePath;
        $variantimages->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work because I have many variants, and each variant can have many photos

Comment: @BudiMan What error shown? that should work based on your postman request, I  already tested and worked.

Comment: In my data there is still an error, the error is in the form of an error in the data being inserted, for example I entered in the first variant array there are two photos, in the second variant there is one photo, but using the code above the data entered into the productimages table are six photos that should be there are three photos

Comment: Please edit your question and add your current full code.

Comment: thank you very much, i have a solution about this. fixed!!